# Kivy APK ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, valueerror, buildozer

When debugging my app, compiled with buildozer on linux, it crashes and gives me this ValueError. On Windows the app runs fine, and I didn't find anything in my code that could've caused this error.

[Debug Screenshot
[image: 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzPzh.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the name of your build can conflict in your mobile phone , if you happen to delete the previous apk and you still have this error you should see if you have Users in  your android phone ,
Some android devices have Multiple user feature and it usually installs the apk on both but when you uninstall it would only do for One of the users.

If you dont have other users then try to use the clean build and change the name .
`buildozer -v android appclean`